A Problem From The All Russian Math Olympiad
There are some counters in some cells of a $100\times100$ board. Call a cell nice if there are an even number of counters in adjacent cells. Can exactly one cell be nice?
I figured out that this problem can be restated in terms of a lightbulb problem where in every move we toggle some cells. Here's was my interpretation:
Each cell has a lightbulb and lightbulb is on iff it is on a nice cell. Now we can view placing the counters as a process . Basically, if we place as even number of counters in a cell it does not toggle the states of adjacent squares(lightbulbs).
So, in a move we can pick a cell and change the states of adjacent cells( basically placing odd number of counters in that center cell)
Now the question is: Can exactly one lightbulb be on after doing this operation?
Now in many such lightbulb problems we try to colour some cells black so that any move toggles an even number of black cells. This allows us to claim that the number of lit bulbs among the black cells has the same parity.
So, thinking along these lines it makes sense for this particular problem to consider a set S of cells such that every cell is adjacent to an even number of cells in the set.
Can someone please help me and tell if the above reasoning is correct and how to use this to solve the problem?

Could you please clarify? Must the sum of the counters in adjacent cells be an even number, or should all adjacent cells have an even number of counters? In the first case, a parity check shows that the task is impossible.

I don't view your reformulation as equivalent to the original problem (but you might be missing some details). EG How does removing a certain (unknown) number of counters to reach a given state, give you any information?

@mau I agree with your first interpretation and subsequent comment.

@mau The sum of the counters in adjacent cells should be an even number. So, for example if a cell's neighbours have $0,1,2,5$ counters respectively, it will ve considered as nice.

Since we only care about even vs. odd totals you can reduce every cell $\bmod 2$ to have either $0$ or $1$ cell.  You should specify that neighboring at a corner does not count, so cells have at most four neighbors.

@RossMillikan Sure, but do you know a solution? I think if we can show that every cell X lies in a such a set S such that the parity of nice cells in S is always even, then we are done?

One thought:  all cells on an empty board are nice.  Adding a counter to a corner square changes the number of nice cells by $0$ or $\pm 2$.  Adding a counter to a center square changes the number of nice cells by $0, \pm 2, \pm 4$.  Adding a counter to an edge cell changes the number of nice cells by $\pm 1, \pm 3$ so you need an odd number of edge cells with counters.  I would try the $4 \times 4$ board case first.

Your reasoning is correct.
Now imagine you place a counter anywhere on the top row. Then you do what is called "light-chasing" in the lights out puzzles: On the second row place a counter directly below every square that has an odd number of neighbouring counters, so that after you are done every square on the first row has an even number of neighbouring counters. Then repeat this on the next row, i.e. place counters on the third row to fix any odd square on the second row. If you repeat this until the bottom of the board, you have placed a pattern of counters such that every square in the top 99 rows has an even number of neighbouring counters. It turns out that even the 100th row has that property, because you get a pattern like this:

Whatever top row square your start with, you get a diagonal rectangle of marked squares, that I have coloured black here. By construction this pattern of black squares is such that every square on the board has an even number of black squares as neighbours. So if you place a counter anywhere on the board, an even number of the black squares will change their niceness status, so the parity of the number of black nice cells always remains unchanged.
To finish the proof you just need to show:

The rectangle patterns on a 100x100 board always consist of an even number of black squares (and so the number of black nice squares starts off and remains even).
Every square of the board is part of at least one of those rectangle patterns.
Therefore no square can be a single nice square on its own.

